# Fetch react updated state without useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having the following code, react always navigates to the following URL when calling the handleContactConnected() function: '/profile/undefined'. profile state is always undefined. This must be related to the state not being updated in time due to the asynchronous calls, but i cannot find a way to retrieve the state when it is ready.

```
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [profile, setProfile] = React.useState({});
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const getProfile = async (phoneNumber) => {
    let response = await checkProfile(phoneNumber);
    if (response.code === 1) {
      setProfile(response.profile);
    } else {
      setProfile({}); 
    }
  };
  async function handleContactConnected() {
     navigate("/profile/" + profile.profile_id);
}

  React.useEffect(()=>{
     getProfile('00000000');
     handleContactConnected();
    }, [])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

To provide more information, this is the format of the data received from the server (from the checkProfile function):

```
{
    "profile": {
        "profile_id": 1,
    },
    "message": "Profile Found",
    "code": 1
}
```

Using an useEffect with profile.profile_id param and including the handleContactConnected() function inside it does solve the issue, however, for design reasons, I need another solution. 
So the task is: 
Waiting for profile.profile_id to be defined then calling handleContactConnected function, without actually including it inside useEffect.

Comment: ‘getProfile()’ returns a promise that you are not waiting for. Put the call to ‘handleContactConnected’ inside a’then()’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues here...

1. You aren't waiting for `getProfile()` to complete so `profile` will always be the initial value when you call `handleContactConnected()`.
2. Even if you did wait, React's state updates are also asynchronous so you'd need to wait for the next render cycle to access the updated `profile`
3. You aren't checking if the profile resolves successfully so there's always a possibility for `profile.profile_id` to be `undefined`

Given your statement...

> Using an useEffect with profile.profile_id param and including the handleContactConnected() function inside it does solve the issue, however, for design reasons, I need another solution.

and the fact that the `profile` state doesn't seem necessary, I'd use something like this instead

```jsx
// Move out of the component, more like a utility function
const getProfile = async (phoneNumber) => {
  const { code, profile } = await checkProfile(phoneNumber);
  if (code === 1) {
    return profile; // return the profile
  }
  throw new Error("Profile not found");
};

export function App(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleContactConnected = ({ profile_id }) => {
    navigate(`/profile/${profile_id}`);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getProfile("00000000").then(handleContactConnected).catch(console.warn);
  }, []);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Why did we move out the component, is it necessary?

Comment: Defining it in the component means it is redefined on every render. Moving it out is slightly more performant but it also makes testing easier